# sorting a text file in c and file handling

Tags: c

Read numbers from an input file. Then sort them using any sorting algorithm. Then finally print the sorted numbers in another text file. I have tried the following code but it is not showing the output in another file.

```
#include "s.h";

#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

    int *a,num,i;

    FILE *fp,*ft;

    char s[5];

    fp=fopen("input.txt","r");

    sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&num);

    printf("%d\n",num);

    a=(int *)malloc(num*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<num;i++)

    {

        fgets(s,10,fp);

        sscanf(s,"%d",a+i);

    }

    selection(a,num);

    fclose(fp);

    free(a);

    ft=fopen("output.txt","w");

    for(i=0;i<num;i++)

    {

        fprintf(ft,"%d",*(a+i));

        fputs(s,ft);

        fputs("\n",ft);

    }

    fclose(ft);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: to start with , check the success of `fopen`

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple reasons for segmentation fault, but most importantly,

1. In your code, first you're calling `free(a);` and then you're trying to access the `free`-d memory by `fprintf(ft,"%d",*(a+i));`. Put the `free(a);` before `return 0;` statement.
2. You're not checking for the success of `fopen()`s. If `fopen()` fails, then you'll be end up accessing `NULL` pointers.
3. You're not performing a `NULL` check of `argv[1]`.
4. you're trying to copy `10` elements [if available] to a buffer having the space for only `5`. change `fgets(s,10,fp);` to `fgets(s,5,fp);`
5. Do not forget to `#include <stdlib.h>` for `malloc()`. Also, put a check for success/failure of `malloc()`.

Note: Please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()`.

Also, we don't know what is happenning inside `selection(a,num);`

Comment: assuming you're on linux, can you compile your code with `-g`flag, then run use `gdb` and tell us the location of segmentation fault?

Answer (score 1):

You are freeing `a` before writing it to `output.txt` !

The end of your program should be :

```
    ...
    fclose(fp);
    /* free(a); too early, still need to be written */
    ft=fopen("output.txt","w");
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        fprintf(ft,"%d",*(a+i));
        fputs(s,ft);
        fputs("\n",ft);
    }
    fclose(ft);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

But you should also :

- test the result of both `fopen`
- test the result of all `scanf`
- test the result of `fgets`

The rule is : always control what you did not produce yourself

Comment: still not getting the answer.

Comment: @kunal51: It works in my tests - even if the output is ugly (what means the `fputs(s, ft)` ?) and if I had to comment out the `selection(a)` call (where is the source ?). If you need more help, show `input.txt`, the source for `selection` and how you call your program.